# How to plot and display a graph in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

[image: Pyplot]

I wrote the code to plot and display a simple graph in Python:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import interactive
interactive(True)

x = np.arange(0,5,0.1)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show
```

And all I got is a blank screen.

And when I remove the "interactive" thing it shows no error but diplays nothing.

How can I display the graph?

(P.S: I use Python 2.7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove these lines, they are not for a simple graphic:

```
from matplotlib import interactive
interactive(True)
```

And you're missing the `()` in the `plt.show()`

```
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error. Replace **plt.show** with **plt.show()**

Answer (score 0):

Just a note for others for future reference the full code should also include plt.figure() with the interactive elements removed.

Here what I came up with.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.figure()
x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

But this may be a 3.5 problem I've not tried in 2.7

Answer (score 0):

You can also plot graphs with pyformulas.
First `pip install pyformulas`, then

```
import pyformulas as pf
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-10,10,100)
y = x**2 + x*np.e**(np.cos(x)**2)
pf.plot(x, y)
```

Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of pyformulas

[image]